# "Hace cuento tiempo" en Java

Tags: java, android, date, time

Estoy creando una aplicación de Notas de borra cierta nota después de 15 dias pero no encuentro la forma de lograrlo.

La nota guarda un valor que es la fecha en la que se creó, ej. 12/05/18 (día, mes, año) y en mi método extraigo los dos primeros números de la fecha (que es el día) y obtengo el día actual y verifico si los dos primeros números mas 15 (que es el periodo que están a salvo) es igual que la fecha actual.

Aquí el ejemplo:

```
String date = listNotas.get(i).getLastModified(); String last = date.lenght() < 2 ? date : date.substring(0, 2); if(last + 15 == currentDay ){deleteNote(i);}
```

Hasta ahí está bien, pero hay varias excepciones por ejemplo:

Sí la nota se crea el 29 de Octubre, el código le sumará 15 y dará 43 pero cómo ningún mes tiene 43 días, entonces el código lo validara como falso.

Lo que necesito es verificar si el mes tiene 30 o 31 dias y cuando pase el límite del mes avance al siguiente mes y los siguientes dias por ejemplo:

```
29/1/19 + 15 == 13/2/19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma sería usando `Calendar`. Dentro de un `try/catch` conviertes esa fecha
en String a Calendar y así agregas o restas (días, meses, años):

```
    String fecha = "29/01/2019";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            try {
                cal.setTime(formatter.parse(fecha));  // parseas la fecha a millis
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -15);          // a esa fecha le restas 15 días   
                String nuevaFecha = formatter.format(cal.getTime());  // obtienes en string la nueva fecha 14/01/2019

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Los objetos de la clase java.util.Date y java.util.Calendar te permite operar con fechas. El método .add te permite sumar días a un calendario respetando el formato de los meses, incluido las horas.

```
Calendario.add(dia_del_año, suma);
```

Teniendo en cuenta que en el primer parametro es la fecha con el formato año(año_actual - 1900), mes, día, hora, minutos, segundos. El segundo parametro es un entero (int) con el valor en días que quieres sumar.

Comment: Muchas gracias : )